# Array push shopping cart in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function

I've just started a PHP course. I was asked to create a shopping cart function using array_push. I don't fully understand the code, can anyone help?
I've created an array called $cart

```
$cart = [
    'user' => 'sholmes',
    'items' => [$camera, $lens]
```

We were then asked to create a function called create item, to put items into the shopping cart. The answer is below:

```
 function create_item(&$cart, $item) {
    array_push($cart['items'], $item);

    return count($cart) - 1;
}
```

What  I don't understand is the last line of code. Why is the return count   $cart -1? I thought the point of array_push was to add items to the cart? Our teacher talked through the solution but I don't quite understand it. Any help welcome!
Thanks
Vicki

Comment: Well, what is `create_item` supposed to return? That said, 99% sure that "answer" is wrong.

Comment: If it was `return count($cart['items']) - 1;`, I would almost suspect that it was intended to return the index of the item that was just added, but it doesn't make any sense to me to do it that way.

Comment: Create _item is meant to add an item to the shopping cart. Our teacher did say the model answer wasn't quite right, but her explanation didn't make sense to me.

Comment: I'd say there is little sense in us _guessing_ what wrong answer might be explained how. You should simply sk your teacher again. That is what she is there for.

Comment: Thanks, we won't be able  to speak to her again until we present our solution on Thursday, which is why I posed the question.  All I want to know is how to make the code work, if  I can explain it then that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The function `create_item(&$cart, $item)` in your case along with adding a new item to the `$cart` returns the position of the last added item.
But `array_push` function already *returns the new number of elements in the array*.
The function could be simplified to the following:

```
function create_item(&$cart, $item) {
    return array_push($cart['items'], $item) - 1;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: Actually the OPs "answer" does _not_ return that value you expect it to return. That is what is discussed in the comments to the question.